# Accessing values in dictionary of counters - python?

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, counter

I have a dictionary of Counters as such:

```
dictofcounters = {'a':{'a':4,'b':2,'c':0}, 
                  'b':{'a':3,'b':9}
                  'c':{'a':0,'b':0, 'c':4}}
```

And I want to find the value where:

- key == value == query
- sum of value where value == query
- sum of value where key==query and key != value

I have tried the following but is there any other way to achieve the same value?

```
dictofcounters = {'a':{'a':4,'b':2,'c':0}, 
                  'b':{'a':3,'b':9}
                  'c':{'a':0,'b':0, 'c':4}}

query = 'c'

# value where key == value == query.
print dictofcounters[query][query]

# sum of value where value == query.
print sum(dictofcounters[i][query] for i in dictofcounters)

# sum of value where key==query and key != value.
print sum(i for i in dictofcounters[query] if i != query)
```

The desired output should be:

```
4
0
0
```

If `query = 'b'`, then the output should be:

```
9
2
3
```

Comment: I guess this better suits http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: What do you expect the behavior to be when a value is missing? Say if you had `'b':{'a':3, 'c':7}` and the query was 'b'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to improve your code is to use functions. For example:

```
def getQueryQuery(dictofcounters, query):
    # value where key == value == query.
    return dictofcounters.get(query, {}).get(query, 0)

def getSumOfQueryFromAll(dictofcounters, query):
    # sum of value where value == query.
    return sum(dictofcounters[i].get(query, 0) for i in dictofcounters)

def getQueryExceptForQuery(dictofcounters, query):
    # sum of value where key==query and key != value.
    return sum(i for i in dictofcounters.get(query, {}) if i != query)
```

One other improvement here is that by using the `get` method of a dictionary, you can supply a default value. This allows you to provide a 0 or empty dictionary if there is no value for the query.

You could also have another method that calls each of these three methods and prints or returns the result:

```
def getAllDesiredQueryValues(dictofcounters, query):
    if you_want_to_print:
        print getQueryQuery(dictofcounters, query)
        ...
    else:
        return (getQueryQuery(dictofcounters, query), getSumOfQueryFromAll(dictofcounters, query), getQueryExceptForQuery(dictofcounters, query))
```

More on why you may want to use `dict.get(i)` rather than `dict[i]`:

```
>>> myDict = {'a':1}
>>> myDict['a']
1
>>> myDict.get('a')
1
>>> myDict.get('a', 'defaultvalue')
1
>>> myDict['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'b'
>>> myDict.get('b')
>>> myDict.get('b', 'defaultvalue')
'defaultvalue'
```

As you can see, if the dictionary has the key they do the same thing. However, if the dictionary is missing the key, `dict[i]` will raise an exception, while `dict.get(i)` will return `None`. If you give `dict.get` a second argument, it will return that value if the key is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but why is `dict.get(i)` better than `dict[i]`?

Comment: @alvas I added some explanation about `dict.get` into my answer